# CSS centering text with margin left

Tags: css

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8CYE/8/)

Is it possible to have centered text in a div that only has a margin to the left?
Basically centering the text according to the black box but not going outside the red box.

One solution would be to put `text-indent: -25%` but when we resize the window and make it smaller some parts of the text will be hidden.

Any ideas?

Update: I want the text to be centered to the black box, but not go outside the red box. And I don't want any margin/padding to the right

Comment: If the problem is that text is flowing out of the container then it is because you have used line-height  http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/j8CYE/10/

Comment: I've looked at your jsfiddle at it appears to be behaving just as you ask in the question (in Chrome). Could you clarify?

Comment: @halliewuud can you show us `screenshot` like thing that what you try to do exactly?

Comment: I want the text to be centered to the black box, but not go outside the red box. And I dont want any margin to the right

Comment: Still not clear what you want ... ? What do you mean by "centered to the black box"??? The black box is on the left, the red box is on the right and you want your text in the red box? So why is there a black box in that story?

Comment: @halliewuud can you check my answer?is this what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Used to  **Pseudo-elements**

```
:after
```

**Write this css**

```
h1 {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    font-size: 2em;
}

h1:after{
content:'';
    left:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:25%;
    position:absolute;
    background:#000;
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/j8CYE/11/)***

More information about ***[this](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html)***

***[About Pseudo-elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelements)***

Comment: Same problem here, make the window smaller and you will se the text going outside the red box into the black one

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly understand what you are trying to do, but `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` does the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/j8CYE/14/

Answer (score 0):

check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j8CYE/16/)

first set you `div` width and then set your `h2`  as `width: inherit`